# how to use third-party dll in outlook add-in using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, outlook-addin

I am creating an `outlook add-in` using c#.

I have one third party dll to include in that add-in project.

I register that dll and include it usind `Add Reference > COM` and add `myapi.dll`.

Its adds the dll but giving the `Yellow Exclamation` on that myapi.dll. I checked the properties of that dll and path is black and disabled and Copy local is set to false. I cannot change any value.

When i build the project i am getting these errors :

> Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "myapi". The referenced
>   component 'myapi' could not be found.

Can anyone help me to solve this please ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Set your project to build as `Any CPU`, **not** x86 or x64

Comment: Its is as Any CPU. But still not working. My dll path is c:\program Files (x86)\MyAPIs\myapi.dll. Does that cause any problem ?

Comment: Did you try registring the COM component ? regsvr32 dllpath

Comment: ya i did. and it registered successfully.

Comment: @Mausami Normally when you add a COM reference VS creates a Interop wrapper assembly for you, it will be under Debug/Release folder. Can you check if that dll is created ?

Comment: Oh no there is no dll in Debug/Release folder. I remove that reference and add reference again but it didnt created now. Do i need to do anything else ??